# Can you use $this in callback to get protected properties of mocked class in phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Can you use $this inside callback to get protected properties of mocked class in phpunit?
Or is there other way to achieve that?

```
 $mock = $this->getMock('A', array('foo'));
 $mock->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(
     $this->returnCallback(function() {
         return $this->bar;
 }));
```

This could be really useful if you think about injecting mocked objects.
Sometimes class has hard-coded dependency for other class, but it creates it with method which you could theoretically mock and create mocked object instead of hard-coded object. Please look on the other example.

```
class A {
  protected $bar = "bar";

  public function foo () {
    $b = new B();
    return $b->fizz($this->bar);
  }
}

class B {
  public function fizz ($buzz) {
    return $buzz;
  }
}
```

But lets say class B does something bad and I would like to replace it with mock.

```
 $mockB = $this->getMock('B');
 // (...) - and probably mock other things
 $mockA = $this->getMock('A', array('foo'));
 $mockA->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(
     $this->returnCallback(function() use ($mockB) {
         return $mockB->fizz($this->bar);
 }));
```

Is this somehow achievable?

Of course without any surprise, currently, if I do this like above then I get error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in (...)
```

Using `use` keyword I can inherit $mockA from parent scope:

```
 $mockB = $this->getMock('B');
 // (...) - and probably mock other things
 $mockA = $this->getMock('A', array('foo'));
 $mockA->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(
     $this->returnCallback(function() use ($mockA, $mockB) {
         return $mockB->fizz($mockA->bar);
 }));
```

but this way I will try to access bar as public and I will get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property (...)
```

Answer (score 7):

As other answers have pointed out, `$this` can be used in Closures since PHP 5.4. A lesser known fact is that you can bind a closure to arbitrary objects and in fact make their private properties accessible like that. The method you need is [`bindTo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php), which returns a *new closure* with different context.

```
$cb = function() {
  return $this->bar;
};
$cb = $cb->bindTo($mockA);
```

Or more precise, your example would look like that:

```
 $mockB = $this->getMock('B');
 // (...) - and probably mock other things
 $mockA = $this->getMock('A', array('foo'));
 $fooCallback = function() use (&$mockB) {
     return $mockB->fizz($this->bar);
 };
 $mockA->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(
     $this->returnCallback($fooCallback->bindTo($mockA)));
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning this feature. PHPUnit also encourages the use of PHP 5.4, so this might be a good time to start making the switch. (also note to self... :) )

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by dev-null-dweller, in PHP 5.4 you can use $this within the closure as if you where working normally in the method.

In 5.3 you can mimic this behavior by doing:

```
public function getCallback(B $b) {
    $self = $this;
    return function() use($b, $self) { 
        return $b->fizz($self->bar);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since php 5.4 you can use `$this` in closures, but you have to return this callback from object, that contains these protected properties:

```php
class A {
    protected $bar = "bar";

    public function foo () {
        $b = new B();
        return $b->fizz($this->bar);
    }

    public function getCallback(B $b) {
        return function() use($b) { 
            return $b->fizz($this->bar);
        };
    }
}

class B {
    public function fizz ($buzz) {
        return $buzz;
    }
}

$mockA = new A;
$mockB = new B;

$callBack = $mockA->getCallback($mockB);
var_dump($callBack() === $mockA->foo());
```

However, if you need to get value of protected properties, you should define public getter for it. This way, test will also work in php 5.3

Comment: Yeah I know I could define public getter but lets say it is an external library or you just want to keep it protected. Whole question is about how to get protected properties of class in given case. So for php 5.3 the answer is still no, you can't do that. For php 5.4, great you can use $this! It is huge step forward! but still I need to change class which I don't want to change. Could you at least create class that extends A to add `getCallback(B $b)`? Need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP >= 5.4, using [`Closure::bind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php):

```
 $mockB = $this->getMock('B');
 // (...) - and probably mock other things
 $mockA = $this->getMock('A', array('foo'));
 $mockA->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(
     $this->returnCallback(
         \Closure::bind(function() use ($mockB) {
             return $mockB->fizz($this->bar);
 }, $mockA, 'A')));
```

For PHP >= 5.3, using [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
 $mockB = $this->getMock('B');
 // (...) - and probably mock other things
 $mockA = $this->getMock('A', array('foo'));
 $mockA->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will(
     $this->returnCallback(function() use ($mockA, $mockB) {
         $barProp = new \ReflectionProperty('A', 'bar');
         $barProp->setAccessible(true);
         return $mockB->fizz($barProp->getValue($mockA));
 }));
```